# Turning off \DeclareSourceMap for bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am wondering if it is possible to turn off the effects of `\DeclareSourceMap` part way through a tex document. Any tips on how to do this?

---

Here is some more information on the situation I am in. I am trying to get a unique citation style to work, which is based around `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=nature,citestyle=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquelist=false,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
```

I use the following to add the journal name to the `authoryear` cite style:

```
% add journal name to inline citation
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

Finally, I use `\DeclareSourceMap` to shorted journal titles in the text. The result is as desired, which is references showing up as **[Doe RSI 2006]** when cited in the text.

HOWEVER, I would like to turn off the shortening of journal titles when I actually print the bibliography at the end of the document using `\printbibliography`. At the moment, my bibliography looks like:

> Doe, A. B. & Smith, J. S. A journal article with a cool title. *RSI* (2006).

I would like the bibliography to look like this:

> Doe, A. B. & Smith, J. S. A journal article with a cool title. *Review of Scientific Instruments* (2006).

But I need to preserve the citation formatting in the text as explained above.

**Is there a way to turn off the effects of `\DeclareSourceMap` directly before the `\printbibliography` call?**

Thanks for your help.

---

A MWE is included below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=nature,citestyle=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquelist=false,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibfile.bib}
    @article{file,
    author = {Doe, A. B. and Smith, J. S. and Author, G. B.},
    title = {A journal article with a cool title},
    journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
    year = {2006}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

% add journal name to inline citation
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

% abbreviate journal names
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=journal,
          match=\regexp{Review\sof\sScientific\sInstruments},
          replace={RSI}]
  }
 }
}

\begin{document}

This works as intended: \parencite{file}

This does not work as intended: 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, a sourcemap directly manipulates the data when it is read from the `.bib` file. Any changes you make are as if you made them yourself directly in the `.bib` file. If you shorten the `journaltitle` field and don't save the original field value there is no way to get them back on the `biblatex` side.

Comment: It would be much, much easier to help you if you could embed the code snippets shown so far into a fully compilable example document (ideally with one or two example `.bib` entries). At the moment we have to rebuild a lot of stuff to get started helping you. Please consider adding a so-called MWE to your question (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Hi @moewe, thanks for responding to the question! I've added a MWE to the main text. Is there a convenient way to store the original field value with `\DeclareSourceMap` so that it can recovered later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` ojffers the field `shortjournal` (not used by standard style), so what you can do is to set the value of the `shortjournal` and use `shortjournal` in the citation. This can be achieved by using `\printfield{shortjournal}` instead of `\usebibmacro{journal}` in the definition of `\cite`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{shortjournal} % changed line
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

and a `\DeclareSourceMap`  that add a value for `shortjournal`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=journal,
          match=\regexp{Review\sof\sScientific\sInstruments},
          fieldset=shortjournal,
          fieldvalue={RSI}]
  }
 }
}
```

The two changes above yield:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is great! There is a small type in your answer - it should be `\printfield{shortjournal}`. With this correction it works great!